# Interviewstreet puzzle connected sets

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to find the total number of connected sets in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253027/algorithm-to-find-the-total-number-of-connected-sets-in-a-matrix)

**THE QUESTION:**

https://amazonindia.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fd6570bd51e1

My solution is not passing all test cases.But I am not able to point out the scenarios where
my code will fail.
Can anyone point out whats wrong with my code?

My algorithm is simple that when you find a 1 make the value of that position equal to a variable called set incremented by 1. Initially set will be 1.
Then checking the neighbors of that position and if any of them is 1 make it equal to set+1.

Repeat the same till you reach the right bottom of matrix. Now increment set and repeat the process till any 1 is left in the matrix(I am deciding this using boolean left).

**MY SOLUTION**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Solution {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


               String no_of_tc;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        no_of_tc=br.readLine();
        int[] result=new int[Integer.parseInt(no_of_tc)];
        int mdim=0,maxset=0;
        boolean left=false;
        int i=0;
        boolean first=true;
        //boolean anyneighbour=false;
        for(i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(no_of_tc);i++)
        {
            maxset=0;
            left=false;
            first=true;
            mdim=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            int[][] matrix=new int[mdim][mdim];
            String[] values=new String[mdim];
            int valuecount=0,counter=0,countchar=0;

            for(valuecount=0;valuecount<mdim;valuecount++)
            {
                countchar=0;
                values[valuecount]=br.readLine();
                for(counter=0;counter<mdim;counter++)
                {
                    char temp=(values[valuecount].charAt(countchar));
                    countchar=countchar+2;
                    matrix[valuecount]counter]=Character.getNumericValue(temp);
                }

            }


            int j=0,k=0,set=1;
            while(j<mdim)
            {

                while(k<mdim)
                {
                if(first)
                {
                    if(matrix[j][k]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j][k]=set+1;
                        first=false;
                        maxset=set;
                    }
                }
                if(matrix[j][k]==set+1)
                {
                    if((j-1>=0)&&(k+1<mdim)&&(matrix[j-1][k+1]==1))
                    {
                        matrix[j-1][k+1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;
                    }
                    if((j-1>=0)&&matrix[j-1][k]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j-1][k]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;
                    }
                    if((j-1>=0)&&(k-1>=0)&&matrix[j-1][k-1]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j-1][k-1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;
                    }
                    if((k+1<mdim)&&matrix[j][k+1]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j][k+1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;
                    }

                    if((k-1>=0)&&matrix[j][k-1]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j][k-1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;

                    }

                    if((j+1<mdim)&& (k+1<mdim) && matrix[j+1][k+1]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j+1][k+1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;

                    }
                    if((j+1<mdim)&&matrix[j+1][k]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j+1][k]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;

                    }
                    if((j+1<mdim)&&(k-1>=0)&&matrix[j+1][k-1]==1)
                    {
                        matrix[j+1][k-1]=set+1;
                        //anyneighbour=true;
                        //proceedwhole=proceedwhole+1;

                    }

//                  if(anyneighbour==false&&proceedwhole==1)
//                  {
//                      first=true;
//                      set=set+1;
//              
//                      result[i]=result[i]+1;
//                      break;
//                  }
//                  


                }
                else
                {

                    if(matrix[j][k]==1)
                    {

                        left=true;

                    }

                }

                k++;

            }
                k=0;
                j++;


                if(j==mdim)
                {
                    if(left==true)
                    {
                        j=0;
                    first=true;
                        left=false;

                        set=set+1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[i]=maxset;
                    }


                }
//              if(anyneighbour==false&&left==true)
//              {
//                  j=0;
//                  left=false;
//                  
//              }
            }



        }
        int counter2=0;

        for(counter2=0;counter2<Integer.parseInt(no_of_tc);counter2++)
        {
            System.out.println(result[counter2]);


        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one test case your code fails at:

```
1
3
1 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

There is only 1 component here.

Also, your algorithm is slow. At every row you're resetting `j` when there is a `1` not connected to the previous one. Try flood fill algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill